# Unable to loop array of objects in angular6

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, observable, angular6

I'm trying to fetch movie data from omdbapi but i'm not getting able to print this value in html

**.ts**

```
import { Component, } from '@angular/core';    
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';    

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private _httpClient: HttpClient) {}
  results: any = [];
  getMovies(title) {
    `enter code here`
    this._httpClient.get("http://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=d5dc2a5a&s=" + title)
      .subscribe((data) => {
        this.results = data;
        //this.results.Search;
        console.log(this.results)
      })
  }
}
```

**Console value**

[image: issue screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably using `*ngFor` in your template on `results`. But since you're assigning `data` to `results` and `data` is an Object, it's giving an error as `*ngFor` assumes an iterative Data Structure.

As can be seen from your Screenshot, there's a `Search` array on your `data`.

Change `this.results = data;` to `this.results = data.Search;`

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';    
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';    

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

  constructor(private _httpClient: HttpClient) {}

  results: any = [];

  getMovies(title) {
    this._httpClient.get("https://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=157f9eb7&s=" + title)
      .subscribe((data: any) => {
        this.results = data.Search;
        console.log(this.results);
      })
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getMovies('The Dark Knight');
  }

}
```

Here's a [**Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-omdb-eg?file=src/app/app.component.html) for your ref.

Comment: getting error Property search does not exist on type Object error

Comment: Strange. You're printing data on the console and it's giving `Search` on the console which is an array

Comment: This is html
<ul>
      <li *ngFor="let result of results">{{result.Title }}</li>
    </ul>

Comment: Change `data` to `(data: any)` inside `subscribe`. I've updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using `keyvalue` pipe as below:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of results | keyvalue">
   <b>{{item.key}}</b> : <b>{{item.value}}</b>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an object in your response. You need use **?** operator in *ngFor loop like this to get array for asynchronous http service.

```
<ul>
   <li *ngFor="let result of results?.Search">{{result.Title }}</li>
</ul>
```

and you can display `totalResults` like this :

```
<span>Total: {{results?.totalResults}}</span>
```